# wxPython Crash on Fit

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to create a wxPython app  that dynamically creates some widgets and sizers based off a data model, like so:

```
import wx

class FooWidget(wx.Panel):
    """ Displays information about an object in the data model. """
    def __init__(self, parent, idx):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(idx))
        sizer.Add(self.label)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        self.model = [0]

        self.button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        add_button = wx.Button(self, label="add")
        add_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add)
        self.button_sizer.Add(add_button)

        self.rebuild()

    def add(self, evt):
        self.model.append(len(self.model))
        self.rebuild()
        print 'rebuild complete'

   def rebuild(self):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.button_sizer,1)

        widget_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        for idx in self.model:
            widget_sizer.Add(FooWidget(self, idx), 1)
        sizer.Add(widget_sizer,1)

        print 'SetSizer'
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        print 'Fit'
        self.Fit()
        print 'Layout'
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The application launches fine and succesfully executes the rebuild() method the first time through. Upon pushing the add button however, I see the the following in the console:

```
SetSizer
Fit
```

And then the application hangs for a few seconds and crashes without reporting an error. My real data model is a bit more complicated than a simple python list, so it's much easier to query the model for what should be displayed rather than maintaining all that state in the view. How can I change this so that I can dynamically change the main window's sizer without the application crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the button_sizer to a new parent sizer seems to cause the crash. Allthough there doesn't seem to be a reasonable cause.

If you edit your class to match the following, it works and it adds the items as expected, without a crash:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        self.model = [0]

        self.add_button = wx.Button(self, label="add")
        self.add_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add)

        self.rebuild()

    def add(self, evt):
        self.model.append(len(self.model))
        self.rebuild()
        print 'rebuild complete'

    def rebuild(self):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        button_sizer.Add(self.add_button)

        sizer.Add(button_sizer,1)

        widget_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        for idx in self.model:
            widget_sizer.Add(FooWidget(self, idx), 1)
        sizer.Add(widget_sizer,1)

        print 'SetSizer'

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        print 'Fit'
        self.Fit()

        print 'Layout'
        self.Layout()
```

Hope that helps to solve your problem.

Michael

Comment: That fixes the issue, thanks. Is there some reason to expect this behavior?

Comment: I am not sure. I think I tried something similiar a while back and it crashed as well. My guess: The sizer object cannot be asigned to another sizer once it has been assigned. But I have no idea if thats right.